# How to plot from csv file in python in logarithmic scale with string as X label

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, plot

CSV FILE :

```
Words,Count
GC,5
AT,3
TA,3
CG,2
CA,2
TG,1
AC,1
```

Code :

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
fig = px.line(df, x = 'Words', y = 'Count', title='Zipf Law')
fig.show()
```

I want to have Words on X label and Count on Y label and plot with data below.

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine for me, with words on X and count on Y !

Answer (score 1):

You have tagged your question with matplotlib. So here is a matplot lib version that is very similar to yours.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("stackoverflowdata.csv")

df.plot(kind='line', x='Words', y='Count', logy=True)
plt.show()
```

It produces this diagram:

[image]

If you remove the `logy=True` parameter, you get this:
[image]

They look similar, but you can see a difference where the logarithmic "compression" kicks in between "GC" and "AT". There is also a difference in the "CA" to "TG" section.

Comment: But i have question it's only Y axis i log scale here ? It's possible to make both axis in log scale ?

Comment: It is definitely possible for both axes to be plotted as log scale. However, I would need to ask you what is the value of ```log("GC")``` and ```log("AT")```???? Logarithmic scales only make sense for numeric values your x axis is not numeric.

Comment: Im only interested, How to do this for both scales.

Comment: If you want your x axis to be plotted agajnst a logarithmic scale, then the data for your x axix must be numeric - not text as per your example. If **and only if** your x axis data is numeric, then you can get a log scale by using `logx=True` on the call to `df.plot`

Comment: I've got another question how can I put everything on my x axis, because when I add more things in my CSV file i dont have everything on my x axis?

Comment: You should probably close this question (i.e. accept one of the answers) and **ask a new question with a complete and minimal example**. It is impossible to answer your new question from the comment as there is zero detail. Given the script and sample file you posted there is no obvious reason why additional entries in the CSV file would not show up.

Answer (score 0):

After you create `fig` you can then call

```
fig.update_layout(yaxis_type='log')
```

Comment: I add this line and when i run project i don't see any plot.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution :

```
x = []
y = []

with open('podzielone.csv','r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in plots:
        x.append(str(row[0]))
        y.append(str(row[1]))


x.reverse()
y.reverse()
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xlabel('Words')
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.title('Prawo Zipfa')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```